# SEPARAR VALORES DE CADENA DIVIDIDA POR GUIONES C#

Tags: c#

Hola tengo cadenas de este estilo en un dgv en C#:

### 33730-1-3

---

### 24253-21-1

---

### 54565-1

---

### 426576-2-21

---

### 76286-

---

### 54673

---

Necesito descomponer la cadena en 3 columnas dentro de otro dgv con los valores que están separados por los guiones, la verdad no tengo idea de por dónde comenzar soy algo novato en C# y estoy utilizando VS 2015.

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado para que se te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Existe una funciona llamada `Split`  seria algo así

`String.split(CaracterDeSeparacion)`

En tu caso seria `texto.split("-")`, Ojo esto te regresa un array de strings,
ya para acceder seria normal, `array[index]`

Te dejo el link de la documentacion para que te apoyes

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto, creo que te servirá. He almacenado los valores en un array, y los he separado mediante un split. Luego los recorro y los muestro:

```
using System;

public class Example{
    public static void Main(){
  
        string[] myArray = new string[6] { "33730-1-3", "24253-21-1", "54565-1", "426576-2-21", "76286-",  "54673"};
        
        string[,] myArray3Columns = new string[6,3];
        
        //SEPARAMOS CON SPLIT Y GUARDAMOS EN OTRO ARRAY
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++) 
        {
            
            string[] x = myArray[i].Split('-');
           
           try{
                myArray3Columns[i,0] = x[0];
                myArray3Columns[i,1] = x[1];
                myArray3Columns[i,2] = x[2];
            }
            catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException e)
            {
                //EL VALOR NO TENIA 3 ELEMENTOS
            }
        }
        
        
        //MOSTRAMOS RESULTADO
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray3Columns.Length; i++) 
        {
            try{
            
                System.Console.Write(myArray3Columns[i,0] + "\t" + myArray3Columns[i,1]  + "\t" + myArray3Columns[i,2] + "\t\n");
            
            }
            catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException e)
            {
                //EL VALOR NO TENIA 3 ELEMENTOS
            }
        }
                            
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo intentaré mañana y te comento como me va, gracias por el apoyo.